# what happens to incoming data, when there is no wsarecv at the moment

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, iocp

I work on multithreaded IOCP Server in windows. To avoid handling with many pending reads, I have always only one `wsarecv` operation on each connected socket. In brief my design looks like:

1. after client connecting, `wsarecv` is posted on connected socket
2. when `wsarecv` is executed, data is proccessed and `wsasend` is posted on the same socket
3. when `wsasend` from step 2 completes (GQCS gets notification), `wsarecv` is posted again.

It means there is a little amount of time between step 2 and 3, when there is no pending wsarecv  waiting for client data, which can appears in any time.

Is this situation, I should worry about or I can assume that if data would arrive at this particular little amount of time, it will be stored in some kind of internal buffer and taken from it at the moment `wsarecv` from step 3 is posted ?

thx for help.

Comment: TCP or UDP?  In either case it will be buffered, in the case of UDP, if it's buffered for too long (as more data comes in) it can potentially be dropped.

Comment: @maciekm consider adding the information that it's tcp to title, text and tags

Comment: You could always issue multiple overlapped WSARecv() operations per socket to ensure that one is alaways available to have its buffer/s loaded with data.

Comment: @Chad It is the newly arrived data which is dropped, not the existing data.

Comment: @EJP actually, it depends on whether you have set SIO_ENABLE_CIRCULAR_QUEUEING or not... By default it drops new datagrams, if SIO_ENABLE_CIRCULAR_QUEUEING is set it drops the oldest first.

Comment: @Martin as long as you're aware that having multiple pending WSARecv() operations on a TCP connection requires that you add code to ensure correct ordering of the reads (assuming more than 1 I/O thread is processing the IOCP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have not disabled the network stack's buffering (using `SO_RCVBUF` and setting the buffer size to 0) then you will have some buffer space within the networking stack and this will be used if you don't have a `WSARecv()` pending.

If you are using TCP then you don't even have to worry when you fill this buffer space as that will cause a Zero Window and the sender will, hopefully, stop sending (see [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html) for why it might not actually stop sending), but even if it doesn't then your stack will simply throw away subsequent datagrams and TCP will eventually resend them.

With UDP it's a little different. If you fill the recv buffer then you will start to drop datagrams. By default the stack will drop the newest datagrams, you can change this by setting `SIO_ENABLE_CIRCULAR_QUEUEING` which will cause the oldest datagrams to be dropped instead.

You COULD opt to always have at least one `WSARecv()` pending on a connection by a) posting more than one to start with and b) posting a new one as the first thing you do when one completes. This works well for UDP but with TCP the problem with this approach is that you then have to allow for the fact that multiple recvs could complete "at the same time" and then you have to ensure that your I/O threads work together to keep the TCP data stream in sync (see [here](http://www.jetbyte.com/handling-multiple-pending-socket-read-and-write-operations.html) for the issues).

It may be more performant to disable the stack's recv buffer and always have enough `WSARecv()`'s pending on a connection as this will remove a memory copy from the inbound data path.